# How to write query without "Cube" function in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, data-warehouse, rolap

I am working at ROLAP on Oracle and i have this Fact Table :
Sales(market_id,item_id,sale), and i have this query :

```
SELECT market_id,item_id,SUM(sale) FROM Sales
GROUP BY CUBE(market_id,item_id);
```

Is there another way to get the same results but without using "CUBE" function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te below query is an equivalent to a query with CUBE(market_id,item_id) clause (gives the same resultset).
But it will be slower, it will read the table 4 times - CUBE is optimized, it reads the table only once.

```
SELECT market_id,item_id,SUM(sale) 
FROM Sales
GROUP BY market_id,item_id
UNION ALL
SELECT market_id,NULL,SUM(sale) 
FROM Sales
GROUP BY market_id,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,item_id,SUM(sale) FROM Sales
GROUP BY NULL,item_id
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL,SUM(sale) 
FROM Sales
GROUP BY NULL, NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it by using ***grouping_sets*** From **Aggregation Function**

and it will give you the same result

```
    SELECT market_id,item_id,SUM(sale) FROM Sales
    Group by GROUPING SETS ( (market_id,item_id) , (market_id)(item_id), () );
```